# Problema al dar formato a label de un grafico de LiveCharts C# WINFORMS

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando hacer que el value de mi grafico tenga un %, pero no consigo dar con el resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del grafico

```cs
            // Solid Gauge Graph
            solidGauge1.Uses360Mode = true;
            solidGauge1.From = 0;
            solidGauge1.To = 100;
            solidGauge1.Value = 75;
            // Graph Gradient
            solidGauge1.Base.LabelsVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            solidGauge1.Base.GaugeActiveFill = new System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush {  GradientStops = new System.Windows.Media.GradientStopCollection {
                new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop(System.Windows.Media.Colors.RoyalBlue,.2),
                new System.Windows.Media.GradientStop(System.Windows.Media.Colors.DodgerBlue,1),
                }
            };
```

Comment: que es solidGauge1?

Comment: Es un grafico de LiveCharts para WPF y Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien más tiene la duda, resolvi esto dandole formato al value de la siguiente forma

solidGauge1.LabelFormatter = val => val.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(val) + "%");

Pueden encontrar mas información en la documentación de LiveCharts